# c++ pull signed integer from specific index in char array

Tags: c++

I have this line of code that I'm thinking may not be the greatest:

```
get_entity_id () {
  return ntohl(*(int*)(&data_[ENTITY_ID_INDEX]));
}
```

data_ is char[] and ENTITY_ID_INDEX is the position in the data_ where the integer is stored.

This compiles and seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a 'better' way to do it. I'm using C++14, if it matters.

Comment: You should be aware of [alignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment).

Comment: I'm not sure that the expression is well defined behavior as it seems to violate [strict aliasing rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing). A safer method would be to copy the data to an `int` via [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

Comment: Oof, I didn't know about alignment.  I'll have to research how char[] of a certain size is aligned and work from there.

Comment: Looks like I can use alignas(int) in the char[] definition, then I'll stick to the boundaries. Awesome!  I'll look into using memcpy instead of recasting and dereferencing.

Comment: If you copy the bytes to an `int` object with `std::memcpy` you do not need to align your data. It will be written to an `int` which is implicitly aligned correctly for it's own requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much information about what `data_` is. Poking around in binary data is something to be avoided unless you absolutely have to. The better way to do it is to use structs or classes. The general cases of having raw binary data are (1) your data is completely defined in which case you can easily map the data onto a structure or (2) it is data with a header and variable length binary data. In the second case a trick is to make a
struct with the header data and have the last element of the structure a char array of length 1 where the variable length data starts.

```
struct data_type
{
   // real definition
   char a[123];
   ...
   int entity_id;
   ...
   // end of header/fixed elements
   char blob[1]; // beginning of some variable length data.
};
```

Then

```
sometype get_entity_id() {
  return ntohl(static_cast< data_type& >(data_).entity_id);
}
```

*Note: This doesn't help if alignment is a problem as pointed out by @François Andrieux (ie you are openning binary files written on machines or codes with different alignment rules).

Comment: Thank you.  data_ is binary data read from the network, from a packet assembled on a different machine (with C#, not that it matters much).  The data is completely defined by the time it gets here.  This data_ is a message of a certain type, pulled out of a packet with multiple messages.  You're probably right that a struct would be best, I'll look into that.

Comment: Right now each message class has a process() function that is used to act on the data... If I turned the message into a struct would that still be possible?

Comment: Maybe a struct inside the class? I'll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: What I show is a POD struct; the binary layout of such a type can map onto arbitrary binary data. If you get the struct right, there is no difference between the binary data pointed to by data_ or an object of the struct type cast from the data_ pointer. Note that if the message is of the "header+variable length message type" you cannot copy it safely using the struct directly, then you have to use the raw pointer to make copies. Using the struct to copy fixed-length messages is okay.

Comment: I ended up using a struct inside my message classes, and using a const length variable in each (returned by a virtual get_length).  I also defined a virtual copy_data that takes a char pointer and writes the struct data to that location.  The change to a struct instead of a raw char[] has made it much easier to define, access, and copy the data.  Thank you!